# ouput css file rather than inline

Tags: node.js, webpack

How to ouput css file as file.css rather than inline in javascript. My configuration look like below.

```
 {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader" 
 }
```

I tested with 
"file-loader!css-loader!less-loader"  //but the content of the file is not css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to use the [extract-text-plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). You can create one css file for your entire bundle or one for each chunk. For example if you want all your CSS in your bundle moved to a separate file, you would add this to your figuration

```
module.exports = {
    loaders: [
            // Extract css files
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
            },
            // Optionally extract less files
            // or any other compile-to-css language
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!less-loader")
            }
        ],
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css", {
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

See [stylesheets webpack configuration](http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html#separate-css-bundle) for more reference

Comment: Is there any way to concat output from both css and less files?

Comment: Yeah just use a single file name `new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/style.css')`

Comment: Does this require you to insert your own <link> to the stylesheet, or can it be injected?